# Determine "tmp_name" before upload

Tags: php, file, upload

Determine "tmp_name" before upload... ?

So I found this : http://phpjs.org/functions/filesize/
I want to check the filesize during the upload process, but I need to setup the tmp_name BEFORE upload to be able to track it.

example of my code :

```
<form id="upform" action="'upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" name="upform" target="upFrame" >
  <input id="uploadPic_input" name="uploadPic_input" type="file" value="" onchange="jsFunctionTostartUploadandTrackUpload( 'tmp_name___HERE___' );" />
</form>
<iframe id="upFrame" name="upFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" width="100%" height="450"> </iframe>
<div class="" id="uploadedBytes" > </div>
```

I want to replace the 'tmp_name_**HERE_**' by the tmp_name because the when the form is submitted, it uploads the file and show output inside the iframe.

```
function jsFunctionTostartUploadandTrackUpload( tmp_name___HERE___ )
{
  $("#upform").submit();
  checkUpProgress = window.setInterval(function() { $("#uploadedBytes").html ( filesize ( tmp_name___HERE___ ) ); },3000);
}
```

Do you understand what i'm trying to do ?

Is there a way like ini_set or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Provided script show size of download files. `tmp_name` is not accessible file, so you cannot measure it size from outside your server.
2. From php 5.4 you could [track upload progress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see why filesize ( tmp_name_**HERE_** ) in javascript won't work because of www.domain.com......

But what about a modification ; ajax call to a php that will check with (internal server path .../public_html/tmp/tmp_name_**HERE_** ) **Will that Works ?**

Javascript :

```
function jsFunctionTostartUploadandTrackUpload( tmp_name___HERE___ )
{
  $("#upform").submit();

  $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: site_url+'/checkUploadedBytes.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:'uploading_file_id='+encodeURIComponent (tmp_name___HERE___),
        cache: false,
        //async: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#uploadedBytes").html(data.uploadedBytes_message1);
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            $("#uploadedBytes").html("_Error").css("color","red");
        }
    });

}
```

PHP :

```
<?php
$uploadedBytes_message1 = filesize ( $_POST['uploading_file_id']; )
echo json_encode(array("uploadedBytes_message1" => $uploadedBytes_message1) );
?>
```